Mean Curvature as Divergence Computation
I am trying to show that if $(M,g)$ is an embedded hypersurface of $(\tilde{M},\tilde{g})$, and $F$ is a local defining function for $M$, then for the mean curvature
$$ H = -\frac{1}{n} \text{div}_{\tilde{g}}\left( \frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad}F|}\right).$$
I have already shown that the scalar second fundamental form of $M$ satisfies
$$ h(X,Y)= -\frac{\tilde{\nabla}^2F(X,Y)}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}$$ with respect to the unit normal $N = \frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}$.
Starting from here, I was told that we have
$$H=\operatorname{tr}_gh = -\operatorname{tr} \left(\frac{\tilde{\nabla}_{(\cdot)} \operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad}F|}\right).$$
But I am not sure if that above computation is correct, as it seems that if we plug in a tangent vector field $X$ there is not even a guarantee than the image $\tilde{\nabla}_X\operatorname{grad} F$ even lands as an element of $T_pM$, so I'm not even sure if the trace makes sense.
We also have that $$\text{div}_{\tilde{g}}\left( \frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad}F|}\right) = \operatorname{tr}\left(\tilde{\nabla}\frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right)= \ldots$$
I really tried to work out some calculations for about two hours and got nowhere. I'm aware that this can be done using a computation in an orthonormal basis (as seen here), but I want to see if it's possible to proceed this way.

I ended up working it out. Start with the formula
\begin{align*}
\text{div}_{\tilde{g}}\left( \frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad}F|}\right) &= \operatorname{tr}\left(\tilde{\nabla}\frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}\left(X\mapsto X\left(\frac{1}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right)\operatorname{grad} F+\frac{\tilde{\nabla}_X\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right)
\end{align*}
Observe that for $X\in T_pM$, so  $X\perp N$ with $N = \frac{\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}$, we have that $\langle\tilde{\nabla}_X N,N\rangle=0$ after applying compatbility with the metric. In other words, the operator we are taking the trace of maps $T_pM$ to $T_pM$.
This implies that we can use the following linear algebra lemma (from Lee Problem 8-2): If $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space, $w\in V$ is a unit vector, and $A\colon V\rightarrow V$ is a linear map that takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A|_{w^\perp})=\operatorname{tr}B$, where $B\colon V\rightarrow V$ is defined by $Bx=Ax-\langle x,w\rangle Aw$. In our case $w$ is $N$.
In our case, we then see that we can now compute the trace of
$$\operatorname{tr}\left(X\mapsto X\left(\frac{1}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right)\operatorname{grad} F- \langle X,N\rangle \tilde{\nabla}_N N+\frac{\tilde{\nabla}_X\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right).$$
To do so, consider an orthonormal basis $(N,E_1,\ldots,E_n)$ of $T_p\tilde{M}$ where $E_i\in T_pM$. If we take $X=E_i$, then the first term has no $E_i$ coordinate in its output and the second term vanishes, and so we're left with what results from the last term. Hence all that remains is the third term. If we take $X=N$, then the middle term leaves us with $\langle \tilde{\nabla}_N N,N\rangle=0$, and the sum of the first and third term leaves us with the same thing, by definition. So everything there vanishes. Hence we find that the above is in fact
$$\operatorname{tr}\left(X\mapsto \frac{\tilde{\nabla}_X\operatorname{grad} F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right)$$
where the trace is only over the $E_i$ coordinates that form a basis of $T_pM$. Lowering an index, we see that it is in fact
$$\operatorname{tr}_g \left(\frac{\tilde{\nabla}^2F}{|\operatorname{grad} F|}\right)=-\operatorname{tr}_g h.$$
Multiplying by $\frac{1}{n}$ for the definition of mean curvature yields the result.
